# If $x$ is in the null space of $A$, how can we fined a basis for the transform $T$ such that $Tx$ remains in the null space of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $x \in Null(A)$.

How can we find a basis for all the possible transformations $T \in R^{n \times n}$ such that

$Tx \in Null(A)$

($T$ does not transfer $x$ outside $Null(A)$)?

Obviously the identity matrix is one of the basis matrices.

Also we can say that the basis depends on $A$ because if $A$ is full column rank then $T$ can be any arbitrary matrix $T \in R^{n \times n}$.

I am also interested to see if we can say anything about the basis in the special case that $A$ is full row rank? For example, if $A$ is full rank, can we say the identity matrix is the only basis matrix?

Comment: I would be surprised if there wasn't a duplicate, probably more generally about finding a basis of $T$ carrying a subspace $U$ into a subspace $V$ (applied to $U = \langle x \rangle$, $V = \operatorname{Null}(A)$), but I cannot find one at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a basis of $\mathbf{R}^n$ of the form $(x, x_2, \dots, x_k, y_1, \dots, y_{n-k}$) such that $(x, x_2, \dots, x_k)$ is a basis of $\operatorname{Null}(A)$. Then $T$ satisfies $Tx \in \operatorname{Null}(A)$ iff the matrix of $T$ in this basis has the last $n- k$ entries of the first column $0$. This set of matrices has an obvious basis where consisting of matrices where exactly one of the other $n^2 - (n - k)$ entries is $1$ and the rest are $0$.

This construction readily generalizes to $T$ such that $TU \subset V$ for given subspaces $U \subset V$ and with a little work to general $U, V$.